# Irregular region masking in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to mask the region inside a contour. My piece of code is as follows:

```
cnt = np.array(list((y, x) for x in X for y in Y))
mask = np.zeros(np.shape(b_contour_map),np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,1)
```

I create cnt based on two vectors of points coordinates, and when printed it looks like that:

```
[[252 251]
 [252 251]
 [252 251]
 ...,
 [249 251]
 [249 251]
 [252 251]]
```

And b_contour_map is an image containing structure contour points.
When I display mask I get the bounding box of the structure, but I need to know only the points inside the irregular contour of my structure (defined by cnt). Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: You want to obtain a similar image as the blue and red one, except have the red area be shaped by your contour and not a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With my collegue we managed to obtain a very similar structure by removing duplicated points from contour, but it's not completely filled. Now we're struggeling with sorting contour points, because we suspect this may be the issue causing improper results. Any idea how to do that? The solution that works 'almost' well is: cnt_duplicates = zip(Y, X)
 cnt = list(set(cnt_duplicates))   maskIm = Image.new('L', (b_contour_map.shape[1], b_contour_map.shape[0]), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(cnt, outline=1, fill=None)
mask = np.array(maskIm)

Comment: Since you have a contour defined by points along the edges you could iterate through the region and test whether each point is in the contour or not.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the order of the points was the issue. I got correct results by implementing:

```
cnt = zip(Y, X)
cnt.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[[1]]))
maskIm = Image.new('L', (b_contour_map.shape[[1]], b_contour_map.shape[0]), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(cnt, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(maskIm) <p>
```

[image: Result]